# Get list of words containing substring in string

Tags: javascript

I have a script that runs if a value entered contains the substring 'sn' but I need it to ignore any instances of that substring if they are immediately followed by either the letter t or an apostrophe.

The reason for this is that the value entered contains the serial number of a device and the script can pick the serial number out because it is preceded by the letters 'sn'.  The problem is that if the user enters words such as "wasn't" or "isn't" (can be with or without the apostrophe depending on who entered it) the script gets the last instance of 'sn'.  I need it to completely ignore those words.

The code I use to check for 'sn' is...

```
var lowercase_name = subject.toLowerCase();
var has_sn = lowercase_name.indexOf("sn") > -1;
if(has_sn === true){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Removed the jQuery part in title and jQuery tag since it doesn't require any of it. Working on your answer right now.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks :)

Comment: There are 1629 matches for `sn` in the lexicon. Filtering out `'` and `t` doesn't remove that many of them. I think you should consider a different approach.

Comment: @TravisJ thanks for your advice but the words used in the same input with the serial number are basic fault reports like 'isn't working' or 'wasn't being seen' so the answers given here are perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something like that with string, `indexOf` not good enough since you cannot have exception. What good enough though is a regexp. Your condition is *"ignore any instances of that substring if they are immediately"*. That mean that you should use a negative look ahead (`(?!)`).

In your case, the good regexp shoud be :

```
var lowercase_name = subject.toLowerCase();
var has_sn = lowercase_name.match(/sn(?!['t])/);
if(has_sn){
    //do something
}
```

- `(?!)` = negative look ahead. Search for `sn` not followed by what's inside after the `!`
- `[]` = *"or"* character. Match any of the character inside the brackets.

Now, if you want to make more complex task, you should take a look at some [regexp tutorials](https://regexone.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a regex:

```
subject.match(/^sn/i)
```

The `^` means to match from the beginning of string, expect characters `sn` right at the start. The `i` at the ends stands for case insensitive matching, so you don't have to convert the `subject` to lower case. This will not work if there are spaces, or any other characters for that matter, before the start of `sn`. If you want to support those cases, you'll have to handle them accordingly.

If you know all the characters that can be expected inside the serial number, you can use regex capturing group to match the whole serial number. The following regex can be used to match any SN with numbers or words:

```
/^(sn[0-9a-z]+)/i
```

The `[0-9a-z]+` means any digit (0-9) and any alphabet character (a-z). The `+` means to match 1 or more of these digits/characters, and since it's case insensitive matching, it will match both lower and upper case characters. The match will end at first non-listed character, e.g. with space, symbol (`+`, `-`, etc.) and so on.

You can see how this regex works: [link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=const%20subjects%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20'sn1234%25'%2C%0A%20%20'snabc123--%2B'%2C%0A%20%20'SN124ASd%20%20125'%2C%0A%20%20'wasnt'%2C%0A%20%20'wasn%5C't'%2C%0A%20%20'isnt'%2C%0A%20%20'isn%5C't'%2C%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20regex%20%3D%20%2F%5E(sn%5B0-9a-z%5D%2B)%2Fi%0A%0Asubjects.forEach(subject%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20match%20%3D%20subject.match(regex)%0A%20%20if%20(match%20!%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20matchCaptureGroup%20%3D%20match%5B1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60subject%20%22%24%7Bsubject%7D%22%20matched%20%22%24%7BmatchCaptureGroup%7D%22%60)%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60subject%20%22%24%7Bsubject%7D%22%20didn't%20match%20anything%60)%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

As you can see in the linked example, you can check if `.match` returned `null`, in which case it means it didn't match anything.

This approach will handle the serial numbers as you expect them, instead of ignoring just the cases you've though of. You should never assume users will write proper English words, or English or even words that have any meaning whatsoever. Ignoring just words where "sn" is followed by "nt" or "n't" is a bad approach. If user types "snooze", you'll still match that as serial number, although I don't think you'd really want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex here. The expression `sn[^t']` will match any string that contains st, but does not have an apostrophe or the letter t immediately following it.

In JavaScript, the code would look like this:

```
var has_sn = /sn[^t']/.test(lowercase_name)
if (has_sn) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
var name = "name"
var patt = /sn[^t']/i
if(patt.test(name)){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without regex :

```
var lowercase_name = subject.toLowerCase();
var index = lowercase_name.indexOf("sn");
var char = lowercase_name.substring(index+2, index+3);
if(index != -1 &&  char != "t" &&  char != "'"){
   //do something
}
```